# get deleted objects from AD

Tags: directory, ldap, novell

I'm using the **`Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard` library** to read out users and groups from Active Directory. That all works fine so far. Now I need to get all deleted objects from AD, which doesn't work so far.

I was able to see the deleted user with the ldp.exe on my server, but have not been able to access the `CN=Deleted Objects,DC=myDC` DN from the Novell Library.

**Here's how I tried to get the deleted users:**

```cs
  IEnumerable <string> GetDeletedUsers(ILdapConnection conn)
        {
            string searchFilter = "(objectclass=person)";
            List<string> objectList = new List<string>();

            LdapSearchResults searchResults = PrepareSearch(conn, "CN=Deleted Objects,DC=myDC", searchFilter);
            while (searchResults.hasMore())
            {
                var nextEntry = searchResults.next(); // hits and then goes to timeout
                String dN = nextEntry.getAttribute("distinguishedName").StringValue;
                objectList.Add(dN);
            }

            return objectList;
        }


 LdapSearchResults PrepareSearch(ILdapConnection conn, string searchStart, string searchfilter)
        {
            LdapSearchConstraints constraints = new LdapSearchConstraints();
            constraints.TimeLimit = 30000;

            LdapSearchResults searchResults = conn.Search
            (
                searchStart,
                LdapConnection.SCOPE_SUB,
                searchfilter,
                null,
                false,
                constraints
            );
            return searchResults;
        }
```

For this I always get the "Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapException: 'No Such Object'" when next is called on the resultset. 
Is there a reason I can't access it like I do?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: updated the question